# Probability of players winning table-tennis game before deuce

Tags: probability, combinations

I'm stuck on a homework assignment and would really appreciate if someone could point out where I'm going wrong, or if there's not actually anything wrong with the approach I'm taking, and I'm just unnecessarily second-guessing myself.

Player A and Player B play a table-tennis game, which ends when the first person scores 11 points. If the scores are 10-10 a deuce occurs which then ends when someone takes a two-point lead. Let $p = 0.55$ the probability Player A has of winning any given round in the game. Assume independence for each round. What is the probability that Player A wins the game?

**My approach**: Player A can win the game in any of the rounds from 11-20, and after round 20, if a deuce occurs, then the number of possible rounds that might be played before they win diverges to infinity. Forgetting about the deuce stage for the moment, I formulated the probability of them winning before the deuce stage as follows:

$$P(Player\space A\space wins\space before\space deuce)=\sum_{n=11}^{20}{n\choose 11}0.55^{11}0.45^{n-11}$$ However this number turns out to be approximately $0.931$. This seems incorrect to me. For comparison I also ran: $$P(Player\space B\space wins\space before\space deuce)=\sum_{n=11}^{20}{n\choose 11}0.45^{11}0.55^{n-11}$$ And the result I got was approximately $0.779$.  Now, I know that the probability that a deuce doesn't occur is given by: $$P(no\space deuce) = 1-P(deuce) = 1-{20\choose 10}0.55^{10}0.45^{10}\approx0.84.$$ And my belief is that since the outcomes which make up either Player A winning before the deuce or Player B winning before the deuce collectively exhaust the outcomes in which the games ends and ***no deuce occurs*** then the following relation should hold: $$P(Player\space A\space wins\space before\space deuce) + P(Player\space B\space wins\space before\space deuce) = P(no\space deuce)$$ However, this isn't the case.

Any help correcting this reasoning would be lovely.

Comment: You have a lot of double-counting.  Your expression for the probability that A wins before deuce include not only the probability that he wins in $11$ games, but also the probability that he wins $11$ games and then loses one, that he wins $11$ games and then loses $2$, etc.  You should calculate the probability that he wins $10$ games, and B wins $n-10$, and then A wins the next game and the match.

Comment: An alternate approach to saulspatz is to imagine they play $20$ games even if one wins $11$ before that.  Now the winner takes from $11$ to $20$ games, so the exponent should be $n$ instead of $11$.  Your calculation must be wrong because the sum of $A$ wins and $B$ wins cannot be greater than $1$.

Comment: Amazing! I didn't realize that double counting was happening. Fixed it and everything works as expected with the last relation I mentioned holding. Thank you!